# Why are Variational Auto-Encoders with low dimensional latent space better generative models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, autoencoder

Here are some samples generated by a conditional VAE with:
1. 3D latent space
[image: Samples generated by 3D latent space]
2. 30D latent space
[image: Generated samples by 30D latent space]
I was wondering why lower dimensional latent space VAEs turn out to be better generators and I stuck upon a logical reasoning.
My intuition says that the posterior over latent variables don't have enough space to spread on *non-existant modes* of data when we have a low dimensional latent space (of at most 5 dimensions as pointed out in the original paper) while high dimensional latent space allows the posterior to spread in all the dimensions thereby allowing the VAE to catch on *non-existant modes*. The paper [Kingma et al, 2014](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114.pdf) has also mentioned the phenomena but has no further explanations on it. 
**My question**: Is my logical reasoning correct? If it is then is there any theoretical explanation behind this logical thinking?

[Code I used to generate samples](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KcecEglmATu-Y9eQA2ueES1IbnurNqLK)